# Implement test environment with Jest on Webpack App

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs

I'd like to implement a test environment with Jest, in an Aurelia JS application (TypeScript). I have `webpack.dev.js` in root project. Where should I start? I install Jest and I have `jest.config.js`.

Comment: Could you share some more details? What else have you tried? What does your test file look like? Do you see any errors? Else, check out the "getting started" (including TypeScript) section on the Jest website https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript